# How can I have my links display a little transparent box on a:hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyperlink

I'd like to display a little tooltip similar to this:

[image]

That little black box appears when I put my mouse over it. How can I achieve this? Is it using jQuery or MooTools or what?

Thanks from this beginnig web designer!

Comment: Definitely Javascript. You might want to retag as appropriately.

Comment: Yes they are (most likely) using a javascript (framework) with an onmouseover event hook. It doesn't have to be a framework (hence the parens above) but it does have to hook the onmouseover event. The arrow on top of the box also makes me consider that it's probably a plugin. Welcome to the wonderful world of browser and DOM manipulation.

Comment: Added the tag, thanks! Any further comments with more clarification?

Comment: You might want to look into the [jQuery "cluetip" plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/)

Comment: that can be accomplished by css alone, but its a bloody mess ... There are like a bazillion tooltip plugings out there, choose one ... heres a small list http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved successfully? Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done through JavaScript. I would recommend using the jQuery framework, as there are a load of different jQuery Tool Tip plug-ins ready for you to use.

[For example.](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/)

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do it with CSS, no need for Javascript.

The black box (the tooltip) can be an absolutely positioned child with `display: none` by default,  and on `:hover` you can show it.

Here is a [little demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gn5s8/).

Example CSS:

```
.tooltipped { position: relative; }
.tooltip { display: none; position: absolute; width: 100%; left: 0; top: 35px; }
.tooltipped:hover .tooltip { display: block; }
```

for the HTML (which remains readable without CSS!):

```
<div class="tooltipped">3 <span class="tooltip">acorns remaining</span></div>​
```

This method will work in every modern browser and IE >= 7. IE6 only supports the `:hover` selector on links, so you need to use an `a` element if you want to support it (or find a different workaround).

Comment: I've never used CSS only tool-tips before, but I imagine that they won't degrade nicely on legacy browsers (IE6,IE7).

Comment: +1 for remembering things can be clever, but let me remind you that too clever designers are too clever by half, often enough. Don't be too clever. ;)

Comment: @Moses: The good thing is, I'm completely going to disregard the older browser, in fact I'm going to put a nice display up so users can use a good browser. "You can view this site but it won't work with old browser. Here use this instead."

Comment: IE7 is not a problem here (with the right doctype), only IE6. It only supports :hover on links. But if you want to support it, there are workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, assuming you had a div properly formatted like thus: (notice this is an extremely simple example. I'm not defining the classes to properly format the elements or anything like that)

```
<a href="AcornsUsage.html" class="acornsremaining">3</a>
```

and

```
<div class="onmouseoverpopup parent">
 <div class="onmouesoverpopup arrowontopmiddle"></div>
 <div class="onmouesoverpopup text">Acorns remaining</div>
</div>
```

You might do something like this

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(".acornsremaining").hover( function() {
    $(".onmouseoverpopup.parent").show();
  }, function() { 
    $(".onmouseoverpopup.parent").hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely looks like [Tipsy](http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/), a jQuery plugin I used.